# JS from HOVER to ONLOAD

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to edit some existing code to fulfill my need.

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/02/08/awesome-css3-jquery-slide-out-button/

It's effect of sliding out content after you hover over it with the mouse is what i am after. Seems simple enough, but i would rather have it on a (automatic) timer. Or rather have no interaction from the user at all for it to work.

Let's say it starts closed, then opens up after 2 seconds. Stays open voor 5 seconds and then closes again.  All without using the mouse to activate it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.slidebttn').hover(
            function open() {
                var $this       = $(this);
                var $slidelem   = $this.prev();
                $slidelem.stop().animate({'width':'225px'},800);
                $slidelem.find('span').stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                $this.addClass('button_c');
            },
            function close() {
                var $this       = $(this);
                var $slidelem   = $this.prev();
                $slidelem.stop().animate({'width':'70px'},700);
                $slidelem.find('span').stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                $this.removeClass('button_c');
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Any tips on what i need to edit to reach my goal?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mj7yumfw/14/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    setTimout(initSlider, 2000);
});
function initSlider() {
    open();
    setTimeout(close, 5000);
}
function open() {
    var $this       = $('.slidebttn');
    var $slidelem   = $this.prev();
    $slidelem.stop().animate({'width':'225px'},800);
    $slidelem.find('span').stop(true,true).fadeIn();
    $this.addClass('button_c');
}
function close() {
    var $this       = $('.slidebttn');
    var $slidelem   = $this.prev();
    $slidelem.stop().animate({'width':'70px'},700);
    $slidelem.find('span').stop(true,true).fadeOut();
    $this.removeClass('button_c');
}
</script>
```

What is different here is that it's using timeout functions to initialize and close slider. These two function (initialize and close) are separated, so you can use them whenever you want.

You can manipulate the time when you're slider opens and closes.
Opening time is `2000` right now, which means (~2s) and closing is `5000` (~5s).

It will work only when the buttons are available as the element to slide is found using `.slidebttn` element.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to do anything after i replace that part of code.  It just sits there doing nothing.

I replaced the source code, so it can't be any errors i might have added in my own version.

`
<div class="button_wrap">
            <a class="button_aLeft" id="button_aLeft"><span>Use your Twitter ID</span></a>
            <a class="button_bLeft slidebttn" id="button_bLeft">Sign <span>in</span></a>
        </div>`